# Rails and ActiveRecord - Nearest points by latitude and longitude

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, rails-activerecord

I am currently porting a PHP application to Rails. I need to calculate nearest venues from a given latitude and longitude.

In my PHP application, I had this MySQL query (clubs are the venues I'm talking about):

```
SELECT cl.*, c.id, c.slug AS city_slug, 
(3959 * acos(cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(cl.lat)) * cos(radians(cl.lng) - radians(:lng)) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(cl.lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM club cl, city c
WHERE cl.published = 1
AND c.id = cl.city_id
AND cl.id <> :club_id
AND cl.deleted = 0
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0,10
```

As you can see, the calculations are being made in the database layer and I would like it to stay like that.

How can I achieve this with Rails, ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL?

Comment: The simplest is Activerecord's find_by_sql method, however any migrations on the relevant models will not stay in step with the raw sql it takes as an argument. Can you afford to make this a model in it's own right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility to do that is use Geokit gem:

https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails

they provides an scope to find closest record from coordinates:

```
  Club.closest(origin: [@lat,@long])
```

in documentation you can find another examples and options.